# How can I avoid using the cursor keys in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

I've started programming after an 8 year break. I'm using [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++) and I like it, but taking my hand away from the main keyboard to the cursor keys to get around the file is really slowing me down.

What methods of file / sentence / character navigation are there that use keyboard shortcuts instead of cursor keys? I know there's a shortcut editor in Notepad++ - how do I assign a shortcut for the cursor keys to, say, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> for right and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for left?

Comment: Didn't they invent Emacs or Vim for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

```
Settings -> Shortcut mapper -> Scintilla commands -> 33 SCI_CHARLEFT
```

and do the following:

1. Click `Modify`.
2. Check `CTRL`.
3. Select `,`.
4. Click `Add -> OK -> Close`.

Now you can press the left arrow key **or** `CTRL + ,`.

You could also define `CTRL + F` for this, but that is the default shortcut for the search.

If you want to, you will have to disable the other shortcut in

```
Settings -> Shortcut mapper -> Main menu -> 46 Find...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've done and very happy. I tried VI to get its keyboard shortcuts so I'll apply those so that I'll be able to look into VI in the future. Many thanks!